# "docker exec container bash" not working in jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, docker, jenkins

I am trying to execute the following commands on the **Execute Shell Script on Remote Host** build step in jenkins.

```
docker exec -it container bash
cd /internal
```

But the `internal` folder is not found as if the `docker exec` command was not executed.

### Question

How to run commands inside the docker container in the **Execute Sell Script on Remote Host** build step in jenkins?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `docker exec -it container sh -c 'cd /internal && some_command'`

Comment: Thank you. I figured out that `docker exec container bash -c 'cd /internal ; some_command' ` solves the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

`docker exec container bash -c 'cd /internal ; command 2 ; command 3'`

solved my problem.