# docker exec -t container_name takes very long time in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, docker-exec

I'm making a new Jenkins pipeline for my dockerized Vue application.

This is my `jenkinsfile` content

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checking out the PR'
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Destroy Old Build'
                sh 'make destroy'
                echo 'Building'
                sh 'make exec'
                sh 'npm run build'
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Running Tests'
                sh 'make exec'
                sh 'unset DISPLAY'
                sh 'npm run test:e2e'
            }
        }

        stage('Destroy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Destroy Build'
                sh 'make destroy'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `Makefile`

```
up:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml up

build:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml build

upbuild_d:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml up -d --build

exec:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml up -d --build && docker exec -t merchant-dashboard bash

test-e2e:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml run frontend npm run test:e2e

destroy:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml down -v
```

While executing the `make exec` in `Build` stage, It takes a very long time without completing the stages on jenkins till I lose hope and abort the run.
[image]

Any Idea why this problem happens as everything works fine on my local machine.

Comment: Are there enough resources on the Jenkins box?

Comment: @AKK Supposedly Yes, but I'm not sure how to check it as I'm new to jenkins

Answer (score 1):

My problem here was in this command `docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml up -d --build && docker exec -t my-container bash`.

I fixed it that way `docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml up -d --build && docker exec my-container bash -c 'npm run serve &'`

Referring to ["docker exec container bash" not working in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818665/docker-exec-container-bash-not-working-in-jenkins)